# Inconsistent style Rd usage section

Tags: r, roxygen2, rd

The new version of the **roxygen2** package has resulted in substantial changes to my package's documentation files. For example, the "Usage" section for four functions combined in one `.Rd` file comes out like this:

```
contrast(object, ...)

## S3 method for class 'emmGrid'
contrast(
  object,
  method = "eff",
  interaction = FALSE,
  by,
  offset = NULL,
  scale = NULL,
  name = "contrast",
  options = get_emm_option("contrast"),
  type,
  adjust,
  simple,
  combine = FALSE,
  ratios = TRUE,
  ...
)

## S3 method for class 'emmGrid'
pairs(x, reverse = FALSE, ...)

## S3 method for class 'emmGrid'
coef(object, ...)
```

Note that the first, third, and fourth functions display their arguments in a single line, while the arguments for the second function are presented in a stacked format. This seems inconsistent. The previous version presented the second function's arguments unstacked (but of course wrapped over a couple of lines).

I would like my documentation to be consistent. If one function's usage presents arguments stacked like this, they all should. But I'd really rather none of them be stacked. How can I control how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by editing your `DESCRIPTION` file to include the following line:

```
Roxygen: list(old_usage = TRUE)
```

(See the "Default usage" section to the [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/news/news.html) for version 7.0.0.)

Comment: Thank you. Silly me, trying to find it in the documentation and vignettes...